# Detect invalid number in prompt

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get the number in a prompt

```
var pr = prompt("Tile size in pixels?", "150");
if(pr != null){
    console.log(pr);
    if (parseInt(pr) != NaN) {loadImage(parseInt(pr));}
    else { alert("pick a valid number");}
}
```

However when I type a word in the prompt the `loadImage()` is executed.

I checked in console and `pr` is the same word, and when I run:

```
 parseInt("word")
```

in console of chrome the result is `NaN`.

But when I run:

```
parseInt("word") == NaN
```

the result is `false`

How to detect invalid number input in prompt?

Comment: For further explanation of why `x == NaN` does not work: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-testing-for-nan-in-javascript.html

Comment: try `if(pr-0.3562344345){ ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isNaN()`

```
isNaN(1) == false // true
isNaN("hi there") == true // true
isNaN("606") == false // true
// etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Try [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check a number

like this

```
if(!isNaN(pr)){
  // Valid number
}
```

you can convert your code like this

```
!isNaN(pr) ? loadImage(parseInt(pr)) : alert("pick a valid number");
```