# Why is typeof x never 'number' when x comes from the prompt function?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting the first function (below) to work correctly. I want it to ask for the age of the user with two possible outcomes. If the user enters the correct value (i.e an positive number) it should return the the age. On the other hand, if the user enters an incorrect value (string, null, undefined, negative number), it should display an alert message, and have the user repeat the process until a correct value is entered and returned.

```
function age_of_user() {
    let age_entered = prompt("Enter Your Age:"); 
    while (typeof age_entered !== "number" || age_entered < 0) {
       alert("You entered an incorrect value. Please enter correct age.");
       age_entered = prompt("Enter Your Age:");
    }   
return age_entered;
}

function confirm_age() {
    let age = age_of_user();
    if (age < 18) {
        alert("Sorry! You need to be an adult to view content.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Welcome to our site.");
    }
}

confirm_age();
```

Comment: The `prompt()` function **always** returns a string.

Comment: ^^ almost always. On some browsers it returns `null` if you press Esc to cancel out.

Comment: There *has* to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: you should return `parseInt(age_entered)` and you should use this condition: `age<18||age.isNaN()` to check age

Comment: I have tried any and every suggestion provided so far but nothing seems to work. For a code that seemed so obvious, this is giving me more trouble than it should.

Comment: If nothing else, you have created a neat way of killing JSFiddle... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/31148728/215552?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. The solutions suggested by both @sphanley and Cruiser worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `prompt()` function always captures the input as a string, even when the input is a valid number. To check if it's a number, you can try to parse the returned string with `parseInt(age_entered)` (or `parseFloat` if you want to allow non-integer ages, although that'd seem odd to me), and if you get back a number, the input is good - if you get back `NaN`, it wasn't valid.

Here's your script updated based on this understanding:

```
function age_of_user() {
    let age_entered = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your Age:")); 
    while (Number.isNaN(age_entered) || age_entered <= 0) {
       alert("You entered an incorrect value. Please enter correct age.");
       age_entered = parseInt(prompt("Enter Your Age:"));
    }   
return age_entered;
}

function confirm_age() {
    let age = age_of_user();
    if (age < 18) {
        alert("Sorry! You need to be an adult to view content.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Welcome to our site.");
    }
}

confirm_age();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. For a code that seemed so obvious, this is giving me more trouble than it should.

Comment: I assure you it does - see the edit with a fixed version of your script.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are showing you that prompt() (almost) always returns a string. You'll need to parseInt the response before you can check it for your age range. But I think your while-loop conditional is throwing you off. Also you need to parseInt() on the prompt a second time, inside your while loop. Try it like this:

```
let age_entered = prompt("Enter Your Age:");
age_entered = parseInt(age_entered); 

while (age_entered <= 0 || Number.isNaN(age_entered)) {
   alert("You entered an incorrect value. Please enter correct age.");
   age_entered = prompt("Enter Your Age:");
   // do parseInt again
   age_entered = parseInt(age_entered); 
}
```

Notice we use Number.isNaN(age_entered). This is a more robust way to determine if a value is a number than comparing with typeof. See this doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` is always returning a string,

Try `parseInt(prompt("Enter Your Age:"))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning a string, and parseInt will save you:

```
... 
  let age = parseInt(age_of_user());    
...
```